# regarding two dimensional arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

if i have created an array like
int marks[4][2];
then the name of the array must give me the address of the first element,as is in case of one dimensional array,but it is not so?
& also
`printf("%d",marks[0]);
& 
printf("%d",marks);`
 yield the same result?????????

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying `printf("%d",marks[0])` and `printf("%d",marks)` gives you different output?

Comment: yes,this is what i am saying.

Comment: @Alfred Which addresses? If you change `%d` to `%p`, does it print the same addresses? If not, which addresses does it print then? Don't worry, i am not trying to extract sensitive info about your machine :)

Comment: yups yups,on changing %d to %p the output comes out to be same,what is happening here @anatolyg:can you explain?

Comment: @Alfred I _guess_ that your system has 16-bit pointers and 32-bit integers, so when it tries to print a pointer as an integer, it prints 16 bits of real information and 16 bits of junk. Cannot know for sure, since you didn't provide the output of the `printf` (this is a hint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%d",marks);
```

Giving a wrong format-specifier leads to **undefined-behavior**. `marks` leads to a pointer to 1D array( i.e., pointer pointing to the first element of first row ).

So, to print a pointer's content `%p` should be used instead.

```
printf("%p",marks);
```

---

And it seems you are trying to print the value at a location `0*0`. So -

```
printf("%d",marks[0][0]);  // [m][n] is the way of accessing 2D array elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

It behaves as expected for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argC,char* argV[]) 
{

  int marks[4][2]={0};
  printf("%x %x %x\n"
         "%x %x %x\n"
         "%x %x\n",
         marks,marks[0],marks[0][0],
         *marks,&marks,**marks,
         &marks[0],&marks[0][0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Has output:

```
12ff44 12ff44 0
12ff44 12ff44 0
12ff44 12ff44
```

All pointers to the first element of the list (except the zero which *is* the first element of the list).

Answer (score 0):

In C , for example A 2D array is treated as a 1D array whose elements are 1D arrays.So if you want to get the address of any of the elements you will have to use

printf("%8u\n",&a[i][j]);

Both the print statements print the same result because both marks and marks[0] are pointing to the starting of the first row of the two dimensional array.

Comment: this is what i am asking,these two are not giving me the same result

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%d` in a `printf` format, the corresponding argument (after default promotions) MUST have type `int`.  Since you broke that rule in both cases, anything could happen.

`marks` has type `int[4][2]` and decays to `int(*)[2]`, which is not `int`.

`marks[0]` has type `int[2]` and decays to `int*`, which is not `int`.

(But I'm still surprised an actual implementation would output different addresses.)